# PHP & MySQL: Special Characters: ¨Ñ, etc

Tags: php, mysql, json

Hi I am asking for help because I have done a lot of thing to show the data in the database correctly. I have a device which inserts data into a MySQL DB with the help of PHP scripts. All the data is shown correctly, but the special ones (Ñ, ó,é, etc...). I use JSON between the server and the device.
I have made many changes and these are the things I have got. First of all it only showed a "?" instead of the character (I?aki). Later It showed null for the full field and finally it shows nothing from the special character is written on.
I have made the following changes but with no success:
In the PHP Scripts:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Besides, in the Database the string fields are in utf8_spanish_ci and the table collation in utf_unicode_ci.

I don't know what else can I do. If I insert a new row in the database I can see it perfectly in phpmyadmin and my device. The problem above happens when the device sends the parameters to the server and I suppose that the php script does not understand the special characters.

Edit: Here is the code for the PHP Script explained above:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['nserie']) && isset($_POST['dni']) && isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['bateria'])) {

    $nserie = $_POST['nserie'];
    $dni = $_POST['dni'];
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $bateria = $_POST['bateria'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO candidatos(nserie, dni, nombre, bateria) VALUES('$nserie', '$dni', '$nombre', '$bateria')");
    $insertedId = mysql_insert_id();



    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = $nombre;
        $response["id"] = mysql_insert_id();

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);

    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
        echo json_last_error();
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Thank you

Solved:Finally I got the solution, and the mistake was in the Android app, where utf-8 was not set.
Here is the change:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
```

Thanks Atri for the explanation

Comment: Can you give me a example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP does not handle UTF-8 at all. As far as it is concerned, UTF-8 strings are just normal byte strings, like any other data string it handles. This is not an issue, as long as you don't *mess with* the strings using PHP functions that don't know how to handle UTF-8 internally.

So, if your devices is sending PHP a valid UTF-8 string, and PHP is merely passing said string to MySQL, then you are fine. If, however, you use something like `htmlentities` on it before you insert it into MySQL - and don't set the charset parameter of the function correctly - then you're in trouble. - So without seeing that code, I can't really tell if the PHP script is messing up the data.

One thing I've noted several times when developing Unicode supporting sites over the years: If it looks *correct* in phpMyAdmin, the UTF-8 value is wrong. Unless it's been updated recently to support it, phpMyAdmin doesn't do UTF-8; only Latin-1. I wouldn't trust what you're seeing there. - You may be able to *coerce* it to show the correct value by manually setting the charset used by the browser. (Not 100% sure about that though.)

One thing I don't get. Why are you setting the content-type to `text/html`? Didn't you say the communication was being done through JSON? Or are you perhaps viewing the data on a website after being inserted by the device through PHP? If that is so, you want to make sure the `<meta>` tag specifying the content-type in the HTML markup is also set to the correct character set. Setting the HTTP header is not enough if the markup is contradicting it.

Comment: Hi Atli, thanks for the explanation. The content-type may be wrong.However, the encodign in the file is set to UTF-8. As you have said, I will have to check if the sent values from the device are valid strings.